# WAV file with QML SoundEffect audio playback is distorted

Tags: c++, qt, qml, wav, soundeffect

My first go at using SoundEffect with QML, and I'm getting mixed results with no clear understanding of why. I can successfully use QML SoundEffect in user interface within an embedded C++ device. The thing I cannot solve is why some WAV files will play perfectly clear, and some will not.

I'm certain my code is correct...its something about how the audio is interpreted. I cannot share the WAV files I'm using...but here's what's happening:

I have two WAV files:

wav_file1_that_works.wav (which is 83kb)

and

wav_file2_that_does_not work.wav (which is 110kb)

Both of these files play just fine in VLC or Media Player or whatever. But when ran through the QML function to play as a feedback for touch on the device, the first WAV file plays just fine, while the second one does not. It does not appear to be a hardware issue as this same issue comes up exactly the same when working on virtual environment. I'm suspecting there is some limitation to using WAV audio within the QT/QML environment? But I cannot find any limits in the documentation. My only suspicion is the file size, or some other specific sound file requirement.

First I declare the sound link to the file:

```
SoundEffect {
        id: playSound
        source: "qrc:/wav_file2_that_does_not work.wav"
    }
```

Then on the UI event it's played (not the exact code, but the event certainly works like this:

```
MyUiItem {
     
        onMyUiTouched: {
         
            playSound.play();
        }
    }
```

and file 1 plays perfectly, and file 2 plays, but with a very distorted scratchy sounds.

I probably don't know enough about how WAV file encoding works, but on the surface both files seems to be encoded correctly.

Comment: what is your OS and Qt Version? and did you test `"file:///your wav file path."` instead of `"qrc:/wav_file2_that_does_not work.wav"`?

Comment: If you play only the sound that sounds distorted through the QT environment without any effects on it, does it still sound distorted? Have you set any gain or volume levels anywhere?

Comment: I test [10MB wav file from here](https://file-examples.com/index.php/sample-audio-files/sample-wav-download/) and it works correctly so the size of your file that you mention was not the problem. could you download and test that 10MB file and say if it works or not?

Comment: Thanks...it's not the path...I can see that it's playing the file. As far as the setting the levels, nope not making any changes. I do appreciate you trying the 10MB thing, that certainly removes that from the realm of possibilities. I'm re-writing how the app compiles as I'm thinking it's compressing the WAV file.

Comment: I'd be surprised if compiling the program would compress your WAV. Did you try playing _only_ the distorted WAV without any additional effects?

Comment: Just saying a `wav` file is not enough, since, as you indicate, some `wav` work and some do not. The differentiating factor is the codec. I would recommend getting an understanding of codecs and how to transcode. Use tools like `ffmpeg` or `Audacity` to view your files and to export them in different formats/codecs. This will give you a better understanding of the various different codec options out there and, it will help you clean up/compress your file to make it suitable for your Qt application.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by refactoring how the app compiles as my WAV file was getting compressed.  So unfortunately this was something I discovered that if I let my enterprise deployment system do its thing it compresses everything including all multi-media unless I apply certain parameters to not compress. And so now this works. Thanks for the help.